# Connecting to Ethereum Clients from C application

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, cpp-ethereum

`web3.js` is a great library to communicate with client node. I have tried using socket programming from C application to first reach nodejs web app in order to make use of `web3.js` services to reach a client node, it is not straight forward at all. I would like to simplify the process by looking for a equivalent lib like `web3.js` to integrate in C, is there any? If not, what is the best practice for C app to communicate with a node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a c++ client, not exactly c, but close enough. [Aleth – Ethereum C++ client, tools and libraries](https://github.com/ethereum/aleth)

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so you might not like this answer but ...**for Ethereum**, the best practice is to ditch C and use the closest thing to it which is "Go".
With Go you have:

1. lots of examples on how to do things
2. lots of open source code that is verified
3. you don't reinvent the wheel

Comment: I agree with you. I'm exploring the possibility of connecting IoT embedded devices (low end sensor node ...etc) directly to Ethereum. Also to publish sensor data to Eth, many sensors software are developed in native C

Comment: as a hobby project, you can...but not on low end. minimum I think is Raspberry pi 3,...which is not low end at all.